# Chrome on Android 5.0 doesn't display inline diamonds

Tags: bug, design

I recently updated my phone to Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and have discovered that mod and community diamonds don't display in posts on the questions list or inside questions themselves in the Chrome browser.

However the diamond unicode character does still appear on the top bar of the site I moderate (UX.SE)

[image: screen shot]

(Sorry for the lack of red lines, it's a screenshot direct from my phone so no drawing on that. Just use your imagination and picture this image with some handdrawn red circles highlighting the Community posts!)

I've checked against Meta.Stackexchange too and see the same thing.

I'm not sure if this is down to the new CSS updates that the UX site got, or if it's down to Lollipop as both changes happened on pretty much the same day.

Comment: That's quite for a long time already (and probably was already reported). Btw, it works in the stock browser, check it.

Comment: @nicael I figured this was something reported already, but can't find a duplicate. Then figured it was just caching, but because it shows it in that toolbar that probably rules that out too. I wonder who else had this, if anyone.

Comment: I do have this problem in Chrome also.

Comment: The one in the top bar actually isn't a Unicode character. It's an SVG image. ;)

Comment: I'm not reproducing this on my Nexus 7 (2012), with 5.0.2 Lollipop. What Chrome version are you using?

Comment: Chrome 40 Android OS.